# How to "properly" initialize and load PointCloud

Tags: point-cloud-library

I am using PCL 1.8.1 in Visual Studio 2015. The following works fine in Debug but in Release mode it crashes with a unhandled exception:

`pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ>("points.pcd",  *cloud );`

I kind of guess it has to do with cloud being a `boost::shared_ptr` and the Debug mode doing some additional initialization.

I also tried to initialize `cloud` like:

`auto cloud = boost::make_shared<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>>();`

or without `Ptr`

`pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud;
pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ>("leaf_raw.pcd", cloud );`

but it shows the same behavior.

Comment: Your code seems fine. Just like in the [tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/reading_pcd.php). Have you successfully run some other example in release? If not, then maybe you are not linking correctly to the release libraries.

Comment: Yes, I can `savePCDFileASCII` in release, but I cannot `loadPCDFile`